Gaining a better understanding of “〜ていく”
The way I see it, “〜ていく” can have many meanings depending on the verb:
Perfective verbs that don't really denote a beginning or an end such as “生きていく” or “読んでいく” seem to have the meaning of “continue to ...” with it and in their past form as in “生きてきた” seem to imply a nuance similar to “has been doing” or “spent one's time doing ...” implying a habitual action over a long time culminating into some current situation or result. Is this understanding correct?
Then transformative verbs such as “温まっていく” seem to either imply “currently warming up” or “starting to warm up”. I'm not sure whether this is purely context or depends on the verb itself. I honestly don't know whether “温まってきた。” means “Has begun to warm up.” / “Is currently warming up.” or “Has warmed up.” and whether this is context dependent on a fixed meaning. Same with something like “わからなくなってきた。”, does this mean “I'm beginning to no longer understand.” or “I now no longer understand.”?
Which brings me to something like “共鳴していく” does this mean “starting to resonate” or “continues to resonate” or “is resonating” or can it mean any number of them depending on context? and if only some of the can be selected, what is the property of this verb that selects this?

ていく refers to the continuation of an action in the future, and it says nothing about the current state. For example, it's usually safe to translate 生きていく as "continue to live" or "keep living", but  technically speaking, you can say 生きていく even if you're currently dead; you can say this in heaven, right before being reincarnated by a god. Likewise, 温まっていく can mean "will (gradually) get warm" or "will be warmer and warmer", depending on the context.

温まっている: either "is currently warming up" or "has warmed up / is already warm"
温まっていく: "will (gradually) get warm" or "will be warmer and warmer"
温まってきた: "has begun to warm up"
わからなくなってきた: "I'm beginning to no longer understand"
共鳴している: "are resonating" or "have resonated / are in resonance"
共鳴していく: "are going to resonate (from now on)" or "will continue to resonate"

